# WebSocket over SSL: Cloudflare

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket, cloudflare

I have a website behind cloudflare. I need to enable websockets over SSL without turning off cloudflare support. I have a PRO plan and hence won't get the new websocket support. I am using Nginx to proxy a SSL connection to a web socket running on a node server. Now, I read somewhere that cloudflare could work with  approved [ports](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-CloudFlare-work-with-) would support websockets. Hence, I'm using 8443 for the Nginx port and another port for the node server. Using wscat it returns a 200 error.

```
$ wscat -c wss://xyz.com:8443
error: Error: unexpected server response (200)
```

I know that the websocket is expecting a 101 code. However, if I visit https://xyz.com:8443, I can see the page displayed by the node server telling me proxy is working. Also, once I turn off cloudflare support, the websocket starts working. Any clues to get this working. I know I can create a subdomain but I'd prefer running the websocket behind cloudflare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're  trying to access this through CloudFlare's network you'd need to explicitly have web sockets enabled on your domain before they will work -- regardless of the port.  As in, even if the port can pass through our network, that won't automatically mean that web sockets will be enabled or accessible on your domain.

You can try contacting our support team to request an exception to see if they can enable it for your domain, but typically this is still only available at the business and enterprise levels.

Disclaimer: I work at CloudFlare.

Comment: Thanks! I asked CloudFlare to enable web sockets but since we have a pro account, we didn't get the functionality. I had to fall back on a separate instance outside CloudFlare to route web-socket traffic. We were worried about being exposed to DDOS attacks but have added some code to stop potential threats. Still, not the best solution we were hoping for.

Comment: @AnshumanBiswas  no promises at this time, but we might be opening websockets more broadly in 2015.

Comment: How do you prevent DDOS attacks on a WebSocket server?

Comment: I use Nginx with some settings to limit connections.

Comment: @xxdesmus Is there any news on whether websockets will be opened up more soon. Currently having to run a websocket on a sub domain that bypasses the cloudflare network.  Means I'm missing out on the marvelous DDOS protection :'(

Comment: @MarshallOfSound we're working on it. Hopefully soon. Different plan levels will have different connection limits.

Comment: fwiw websockets is available for all levels of accounts now https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169466-Can-I-use-CloudFlare-with-WebSockets-